# Wrong year in time conversion for final day of the year

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, date-conversion

The below code snippet prints the wrong year. Am I doing something wrong here? It prints the date time as `2018-12-31 00:00:00` but it should really be `2017-12-31 00:00:00`. I converted the same epoch in JavaScript and it works fine. I also set the time zone as `UTC` and it gives the result as `2017-12-30 18:30:00` but setting the timezone as `Asia/Calcutta` increments it by a year. What am I missing here?

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter format  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String time = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1514658600000L), ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")).format(format);

        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` should probably be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: I tried your code both by using YYYY and by using yyyy It works good

Comment: December 31, 2017 was a Sunday. In week schemes where Sunday is the first day of the week (e.g., in the USA), the week year will be 2018, that is, wrong. In the ISO week scheme used in many countries Monday is the first day of the week, so the week year of that Sunday will be 2017, that is, correct in this case. The format pattern string is still wrong and will give wrong results in other cases, Also @AngeloImmediata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY':

`DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

From the docs :

> ```
> Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
> y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
> Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
> ```